# Why do we use the plugins in the crm 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

"A plug-in is custom business logic (code) that you can integrate with Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 to modify or augment the standard behavior of the platform."

my question is :
What the ideal scenario/conditions  to use the plugins in the CRM dynamics, before the using the plugins, what types of conditions considers for use of the plugin.

Comment: I think the description is self-explanatory. Use a plugin whenever you need to "modify or augment the standard behavior of the platform". Pretty clear. You can use a plugin to modify the behavior of just about any action in CRM, for example saving or retrieving a record.

Comment: @Egor : my concern that, why we need to modify the standard behavior of the platform, instead of change of standard behavior, can we go with anoth er platform/applicaion?

Comment: Because if the platform fulfills most of your requirements, it's much easier to slightly modify it then build a whole new app. It would take you a few days at most to write a typical plugin, but it would take you many, many years to write CRM. It's like saying "why would I want to change my desktop background, can't I just write a new operating system that has my desired background by default?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plug-ins have many uses. This includes the following:

- Performing complex platform level data validation
- Performing auto-number generation
- Providing integration with other applications
- Executing complex business logic

Answer (score 2):

You should use plugins under any of the following conditions:

- When you need to enforce business logic in your database that you cannot accomplish reasonably with built in tools like workflows
- When your business logic must be executed synchronously
- When you need to integrate with external services (address verification or payment processing for example)
- When you have a multi-tiered solution where you want to inherit business logic

Answer (score 1):

We write the plugin, when MS CRM tools do not provide the such works then we write the plugin and perform that works.
Like 
Any integration in MS CRM tools or want generate auto-number,Execute complex Business Logic etc.

Comment: Could you make more , which types of work don't provide by MSCRM in the Customer Relationship management system or what type of need, which to force to use plug in

Answer (score 1):

Plugins are `Call Out` a custom logic(`.dll`) to implement business logic. It can be registered on `CRUD` events over three zone `Pre-Validation`,`Pre-Operation` & `Post-Operation` which lets you capture the data that is going to/coming from the `database` over the transaction between UI & Back-end.

So by running a custom code in these event the developers will be able to perform business operation between it. Although there are many examples to quote but mostly it is used when the in-build system workflow/process is not capable to implement the Business requirements.